# Unable to find 'ng' in module... - broken Intellisense?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, typescript1.4

When trying to reference external modules, Intellisense spits out an error along the lines of..

```
Could not find symbol 'ng' in global module
```

or..

```
Could not find symbol 'ng' in module 'App' // my main module
```

..even though I'm correctly referencing the typescript definitions (using definitelyTyped):

#### _references.ts

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts" />

declare var angular: ng.IAngularStatic; // unable to find in global module
```

#### SomeDirective.ts

```
/// <reference path="_references.ts" />

module App {
    export class SomeDirective implements ng.IDirective // unable to find in module 'App'
}
```

Interestingly, compiling the *.ts files with grunt-typescript works fine and the application runs without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have "declare module ng" somewhere in your code base. Please change it to "declare module angular"

Details : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/pull/3851#issue-60749247

**Update**

What I mean is search for `declare module ng`. There should be *zero* results (which I suspect is not the case for your codebase).

Note: `angular.d.ts` now does `declare module angular` not `declare module ng`.

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angularjs/angular.d.ts#L26

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. ng is declared by angular.d.ts (definitelyTyped) and not in my code base?

Comment: This only seems to work partially. angular-ui, ui-router etc. are now happy,  but for the others I receive e.g. 'Could not find symbol 'IDirective' in module 'angular'. I've updated definitelyTyped to the latest version.

Comment: Okay, I think I see it. In the typescript definitions of angularjs, there is a module called `angular` with all the interfaces I need. However, there is also a global variable declared as `angular`, which is of type IAngularStatic. So when I try to reference an interface in module `angular`, Intellisense assume that I mean the variable and thus fails to find the interface. When hovering over `angular`, it clearly shows that it's of type `IAngularStatic` and not the module. Is this on purpose? Looks like the renaming from `ng` to `angular` did indeed break stuff. :/

Comment: I had this issue, because I still had a angular translate type definition file in my solution which defined the module 'ng'. Replacing this file with a new version solved the issue for me. https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/angular-translate/angular-translate.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. I replaced in typings "declare namespace angular" to "declare module angular" and all is great now!

typings were from here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

I've included this one file angular.d.ts (/// )